# How to remove pressing effect on ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, uwp, listviewitem, uwp-xaml

I have a `ListView`, when I select a row with mouse, while I am pressing, that row gets some padding or margin, I don't know what it is, I just want it not to happen, just select a row without any effect like when I select a row with keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default behavior, you have to alter the style for the `ListViewItem`. You can find these styles on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) or on your local drive:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml

The visual states in question are most likely `Pressed` and `PressedSelected`. Alter these visual states to whatever you would like the `ListView` to do.

```
<!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem -->
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded">
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
<Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
<Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
<Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            ...
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 Duration="0"
                                 To="1"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            ...
            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 Duration="0:0:0"
                                 To="1"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 Duration="0"
                                 To="1"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          ...
```

Comment: should I bring all the code for it? can I just bring pressed and ... blocks ( those that I want to change)?

Comment: You have to bring in everything under `Setter Property="Template"` as this is a block.

Comment: Some more info on styles and templates if you want to know more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx